# Generated Script via SMO can't be executed

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

I'm using Smo to create a SQL script of a existing database. For testing purposes I deleted my database and copied the script into a new query to create it again. 
Unfortunately, this process produces an error.

```
'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch
```

Since I'm creating several views, this error is displayed several times on my messages tab in SQL Server Management Studio.
When I looked for solutions I found out that the keyword "Go" before "Create View" was apparently missing.
Is an option included in the class "ScriptingOptions" to append "GO" in the generated script?

Code:

```
public void GenerateSQLScripts(string dbName)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Server server = new Server(SqlServer);
        Database db = server.Databases[dbName];


        var scriptopt = new ScriptingOptions();
        scriptopt.TargetServerVersion = SqlServerVersion.Version105; // Windows 2008 R2
        scriptopt.AnsiPadding = true;
        scriptopt.WithDependencies = true;
        scriptopt.IncludeHeaders = true;
        scriptopt.SchemaQualify = true;
        scriptopt.ExtendedProperties = true;
        scriptopt.TargetDatabaseEngineType = DatabaseEngineType.Standalone;
        scriptopt.IncludeDatabaseContext = true;
        scriptopt.ScriptDrops = false;
        scriptopt.ScriptData = false;
        scriptopt.ScriptSchema = true;
        scriptopt.DriAllConstraints = true;
        scriptopt.DriForeignKeys = true;
        scriptopt.Indexes = true;
        scriptopt.DriPrimaryKey = true;
        scriptopt.DriUniqueKeys = true;
        scriptopt.DriChecks = true;
        scriptopt.AllowSystemObjects = false;
        scriptopt.AppendToFile = false;

        // script Tables
        foreach (Table t in db.Tables)
        {
            if (!t.IsSystemObject)
            {
                StringCollection sc = t.Script(scriptopt);
                foreach (string s in sc)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(s);
                }
            }

        }

        //Script Stored Procedures
        foreach (StoredProcedure sp in db.StoredProcedures)
        {
            if (!sp.IsSystemObject)
            {
                var sc = sp.Script(scriptopt);
                foreach (string s in sc)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(s);
                }
            } 

        }

        //Views
        foreach(View v in db.Views){
            if (!v.IsSystemObject)
            {
                StringCollection sc = v.Script(scriptopt);
                foreach (string s in sc)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(s);
                }
            }

        }
        File.WriteAllText(Path, sb.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: Actually GO is NOT a keyword. It is the default batch separator in SSMS. It can be replaced with just about anything. Not sure how to have SMO include batch separators in the generated script.

Comment: @SeanLange Didn't know that, was referring to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340332/create-view-must-be-the-first-statement-in-a-query-batch

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? Seems like [scriptbatchterminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.scriptingoptions.scriptbatchterminator?view=sqlserver-2016) does exactly this.

Comment: @SMor Thanks for the advice, but I got the same error again. The script also has the same number of lines as before the activation of the option.

Answer (score 0):

The property you are looking for is called "NoCommandTerminator". Set it to false and you should be good. 
I found this out by trial and error. Actually I'm using the SMO as well and I'm serializing the ScriptingOptions to an XML-File to be able to change it later on. In my configuration I stated also help, how to configure it and this row is what I wrote for adding GO statements:

```
  <NoCommandTerminator>false</NoCommandTerminator> <!-- Should we include a GO between statements? -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad news, you're SOL

the batch terminators only go into the file irrespective of any options/flags :(

The only way i've ever figured out to do it is to set Options.ToFileOnly = $true, script it to a temp location and Get-Content it

So yes, MS has decided that the output file and string collection contain different things.

Answer (score 0):

wow, Look someone build the same tool it's make my exciting. 
My experience is you need manual attach GO keyword in your create script. If you script include Go keyword, that cannot execute by SqlConnection 
And Only Execute by SMO ConnectionContext
e.g

```
smoServer.ConnectionContext.BeginTransaction();
var result = smoServer.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(_createViewScript);
smoServer.ConnectionContext.CommitTransaction();
```