# Don't understand 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: t-sql, view

I am trying to create a View for temporary data I only need during the SQL run.

I get the error:

> "'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch."

I searched on that and see it was asked about on Stack Overflow already here:  ['CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340332/create-view-must-be-the-first-statement-in-a-query-batch)

However, my SQL code looks like it should but I still get the error. First, I create a table called `@StatusTable` but that table wasn't working like I wanted.  So I tried creating a View.

```
DECLARE @DOC INT;

DECLARE @StatusTable TABLE
(
    status VARCHAR(8000)
)
INSERT INTO @StatusTable

 Select Status = ( select   CONCAT(ls.ItemText, '/', st.ItemText ) as Status from  Inmate_Legal_Status ils 
 Left join  jt_list_items ls on ls.ItemID =  ils.LegalStatusID 
 Left join  jt_list_items st on st.ItemID =  ils.StatusTypeId 
 where ArrestNo = @doc and ils.RecordDeleted = 0
 order by ils.CreatedTime desc  FOR XML PATH('')
)
-- table

USE @StatusTable;
GO

create view MyView as 
  Select Status = ( select   CONCAT(ls.ItemText, '/', st.ItemText ) as Status from  Inmate_Legal_Status ils 
  Left join  jt_list_items ls on ls.ItemID =  ils.LegalStatusID 
  Left join  jt_list_items st on st.ItemID =  ils.StatusTypeId 
  where ArrestNo = @doc and ils.RecordDeleted = 0
GO
```

I get three errors:

1. Incorrect syntax near GO.
2. 'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch
3. Incorrect syntax near @StatusTable

Comment: Looks like you are trying to combine dynamic SQL and standard T-SQL. The `USE` statement is for changing database context. And you can't have parameters in Views.

Comment: I don't know difference between dynamic SQL and standard T-SQL.  Can you tell me which is the dynamic in my code?